# Best practice for matching nested elements in CSS

Tags: css

I did some research and couldn't definitively find the answer to whether its best practice to use a class selector or tag selector for a nested element. Say I have the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item-content" >
            <img src="/images/flags/fr.png" class="country-flag">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I could write :

```
.list-item-content img{
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Or

```
.list-item-content .country-flag{
    vertical-align: middle;     
}
```

Which is best practice? Since the browser matches rules right to left, I would assume the second way is better as with the first way the browser with first match ALL images, then check the parents....

Comment: You are correct. The second method is better, and for exactly the reason you mentioned. I guess you answered your own question xD

Answer (score 1):

For more specific css you have to use both like following :-

```
.list-item-content img.country-flag{
    vertical-align: middle;     
}
```

It will define more clear nesting structure.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think using two classes in the rule like $('.class1 .class2') matches more efficiently and is better practice.  And maybe rarely need 3 classes.

In case you are very sure a class is unique, then $('.class1') maybe enough.

Comment: Moreover, I think the rule like $('.class1 img') and $('.class1 .class2 img') are also highly practical as soon as the criteria are unique enough.  Actually I am not yet caring the efficiency issue you mentioned about matching from right to left, because convenience, cleanness and readability seems more important.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the complexity of your project and preference of your team.

In term of performance, selecting nesting items with something like this

```
 .list-item-content .country-flag{}
```

which translage to

```
 select  .country-flag elements descendant of .list-item-content element
```

could have a performance penalty on large project (DOM) or in device with limited capabilities (like smart tvs or old mobile devices).

In order to mitigate this risk you can try to use a name convention which will help you to prevent selecting nesting element in an expensive way.

One of the methodology is called **[BEM](https://en.bem.info/method/naming-convention/)**.

Briefly the convention is as follow:

```
.block represents the higher level of an abstraction or component.
.block__element represents a descendent of .block that helps form .block as a whole.
.block--modifier represents a different state or version of .block.
```

So you HTML could be rewritten like this:

```
<div class="componenet">
<ul>
    <li class="componenet__list" >
            <img src="/images/flags/fr.png" class="componenet__list-flag">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

in this case you can select directing your class

```
.componenet__list-flag {}
```

More info here:

http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time you will not trying to match all img therefore 2nd convention is prefered

```
.list-item-content .country-flag{
    vertical-align: middle;     
}
```

This is another good practice by Harsh Sanghani as well.

```
.list-item-content img.country-flag{
    vertical-align: middle;     
}
```